# Сделал часы прокомментируйте код

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```js
function clock(){
  var hour = document.querySelector('.hour');
  var min = document.querySelector('.min');
  var sec = document.querySelector('.sec');
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  hour.innerHTML = hours;
  min.innerHTML = minutes;
  sec.innerHTML = seconds;
  if(hours < 10){
     hour.innerHTML = '0' + hours;
  }
  if(minutes < 10){
    min.innerHTML = '0' + minutes;
  }
  if(seconds < 10){
    sec.innerHTML = '0' + seconds;
  }
};
clock()

setInterval(clock, 1000)
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <span class="hour">hh</span>:<span class="min">mm</span>:<span class="sec">ss</span>
</div>
```

Сделал часы прокомментируйте код

@Qwertiy написал код как я его понял

1. Создается функция showTime с параметрами date, selectors и root в который присваивается document
2. Доступ к DOM начинается с объекта document через который можно получить доступ к любым узлам
3. в переменную hms присваивается массив где в числовых индексах хранится значение часы, минуты, секунды
4. Создается цикл for где в переменной q присваивается 0 (счетчик) и почему q если по правилам хорошего тона нужно использовать i (всегда встречал i), в переменную n присваивается  математический метод который дает наименьшее число
5. Math.min выбирает между selectors которое преобразуем в число с помощью свойства length и hms - массив в котором храним время
6. если q < n идем в тело цикла 
   7 root.querySelector(selectors[q]) в зависимости от числа в q выбирается часы, минуты, секунды (что-то одно)
7. textContent обладает преимуществом (или недостатком он не понимает html элементы поэтому вставляет их как текст)
8. Дальше идет тернарный оператор если условие выполняется перед числом добавляем 0 иначе нет
9. Создается функция updateTimers в теле функции создаем локальную переменную date (она видна только в этой функции) и присваиваем вcтроенный объект в js new Date (new означает что создается объект с помощью с конструктора объектов  также в объекте Date есть разные методы - это указывает на статические фабричные методы
10. Затем вызываем функцию showTime с аргументами
11. updateTimers() - означает что мы ее вызываем
12. updateTimers() добавляем в интервал где она вызывается каждую секунды (1000 указывает на милисекунды)
13. Правильно я  понял его код ?
14. Извиняюсь за косноязычие

Comment: к однозначным числам не хватает ведущего нуля слева. получается некрасивое время `9:25:1`

Comment: при запуске видна запись hh:mm:ss

Comment: @Grundy моргните когда нажимаете клавишу выполнить код :))

Comment: @Grundy а так спасибо, не знаю как исправить :(

Comment: @Lexx918  спасибо

Comment: @Leks, чтобы этого не было, первый раз нужно выполнить функцию сразу, а не по истечении первого интервала.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо

Comment: @Lexx918 снова здравствуйте исправил замечание правильно ?

Comment: @Grundy снова здравствуйте исправил замечание правильно ?

Comment: почему функция `close` называется? почему дублируется код?

Comment: @ThisMan здравствуйте 1) close ведь можно перевести как часы 2) чтобы к однозначным числам добавить 0

Comment: @ThisMan на гуглил произошла ошибка

Comment: `close ведь можно перевести как часы` может быть `clock`? `close` вроде ни как часами быть не может

Comment: у вас код в интервале и функции дублируется, почему бы не переиспользовать функцию

Comment: @ThisMan опыта и знаний мало :(

Comment: @ThisMan исправил посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @ThisMan скажите фильтры сложнее сделать чем часы ? фильтр по полам к примеру ?

Comment: `setInterval` не гарантирует времени между итерациями. он только поставит задачу в очередь. может получиться, что у вас на часах за 1 секунду время тикнет сразу на 2. например, таймер первый раз тикает в 1.999 и на часах 1 секунда, а потом тикает в 3.001 и на часах сразу 3 секунды, хотя между тиками всего 1.002 и на глаз кажется что одна. лучше тикать чаще и проверять внутри функции сколько реально времени прошло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ну копипаст функции же.
2. Почему она так называется?
3. Не надо использовать `innerHTML` вместо `textContent`.
4. Нет смысла сохранять в переменные элементы, к которым обращаешься только 1 раз.

```js
function showTime(date, selectors, root = document) {
  var hms = [date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()];

  for (var q=0, n=Math.min(selectors.length, hms.length); q<n; ++q) {
    root.querySelector(selectors[q]).textContent = hms[q] < 10 ? "0" + hms[q] : hms[q];
  }
};

function updateTimers() {
  var date = new Date;
  showTime(date, ['.hour', '.min', '.sec'], document.getElementById('clock-hms'));
  showTime(date, ['.hour', '.min'], document.getElementById('clock-hm'));
}

updateTimers();
setInterval(updateTimers, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="clock-hms">
  <span class="hour"></span>:<span class="min"></span>:<span class="sec"></span>
</div>
<div id="clock-hm">
  <span class="hour"></span>:<span class="min"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: щас у человека мозг взорвется:D

Comment: @ThisMan, вроде нормально же?

Comment: просто, судя по комментариям тс, у него знания минимальные, а тут и параметры по умолчанию и циклы и все прочее

Comment: @ThisMan, хм.. а параметр по умолчанию я сделал, но не использовал...

Comment: @Qwertiy здравствуйте я посмотрел ваш код и написал как я его понял посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @ThisMan  скажите я правильно понял код Qwertiy

Comment: @Leks 1. _"root в который присваивается document"_ - не присваивается, это значение по умолчанию, а не присваивание. 2. Муть какая-то. 4. _"и почему q"_ - просто мой стиль. 4. _"в переменную n присваивается математический метод"_ - нет, метод не присваивается, а вызывается. 5. Бред какой-то. 9. _"это указывает на статические фабричные методы"_ - не понял, ерунда какая-то. До этого места верно. 12. _"updateTimers()"_ - зря тут скобки.

Comment: @Qwertiy 1) это значение по умолчанию т.к. слово document зарезервировано?  и так происходит со всеми зарезервированными  словами ?

Comment: 4) ошибся в написании математические методы не присваиваются, а вызываются

Comment: @Qwertiy  5) фабричный метод так будет правильно ?

Comment: @Leks 1. Нет, слово document не зарезервировано и это вообще никак не связано с параметрами по умолчанию. 4. Почему именно математические? При желании присваиваются. Любые. 5. Да каким боком тут вообще фабричный метод??

Comment: @Qwertiy 5) Объект Date можно вызвать с различными методами это относится к фабричным методам ?

Comment: @Leks, нет, фабричные методы тут вообще не при чём.

Comment: @Qwertiy Здравствуйте пункт 4 над вашим кодом я же использую функцию локальную область видимости, а не глобальную

Comment: @Qwertiy пункт 3 над вашим кодом в код пользователь не может вставить свой HTML код почему тогда не надо так делать ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93764/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-leks).

Answer (score 2):

Вот так лаконично: основная идея - привязка метода к элементу через атрибуты

```js
function update() {
  var date = new Date
  document.querySelectorAll('#clock span').forEach(function(span) {
    span.textContent = String(date[span.className]()).padStart(2, '0');
  });
}

update();

setInterval(update, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <span class="getHours"></span>:<span class="getMinutes"></span>:<span class="getSeconds"></span>
</div>

<div id="clock">
  <span class="getHours"></span>:<span class="getMinutes"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: я не знаю ES6 :(((

Comment: @Leks убрал стрелочные функции

Comment: спасибо придется и Ваш код описывать :)

Comment: @Leks а зачем? просто примите к сведению

Comment: `new Date()` может измениться между вызовами и получится фигня.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Вы сами написали принять к сведению так лучше принимается :)

Comment: @Qwertiy а я уже поменял =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ага, так лучше :)

Comment: @Qwertiy `console.log([...new Set(Array(1000000).fill(0).map(() => new Date().getTime()))].length)` // 226 просто для интереса вызвал